# Eliminar estos logs de Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy haciendo un programa Java con Hibernate, y estos logs la verdad es que me molestan bastante. Alguien sabe quitarlos? Las letras en rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hibernate usa JBoss Logging](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-logging-guide/), que lo que hace es pasar la gestión de los logs a otra librería, según se encuentren en el *classpath*.

Como supongo que no has puesto ninguna tú, eso significa que acaba pasando los *logs* al sistema de *logging* del JDK, que es lo que tienes que configurar.

Hay varias formas de configurar el *logging* del JDK:

- [Vía programa, "reseteando" los handlers](http://www.javathinking.com/2011/09/turning-off-jdk-logging.html):

  ```
  LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
  Logger globalLogger = Logger.getLogger(java.util.logging.Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
  globalLogger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
  ```
- [Mediante un fichero de configuración](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html), un fichero de texto tal que:

  > handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
  >
  > config   =
  >
  > org.hibernate.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
  >
  > org.hibernate.useParentHandlers  = false
  >
  > org.hibernate.level              = OFF

  Esto dice que todos los logs enviados a `org.hibernate` están desactivados.

  Para usar esta configuración, tienes que definir la propiedad `java.util.logging.config.file` con la ruta del fichero; esto se hace pasando un parámetro `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=[rutal fichero conf]` al invocar la JVM.